# How do apiarists cultivate homeycomb without nicotine or a smoker?

Tags: entomology

I don't see a better stack site for this so I'll just post it here. I remember an apiarist I met saying they cultivated honeycomb without a smoker or anything like that, but I never asked them how. Figured it would be interesting to ask if there is any consensus on how one could do that without bees swarming or anything like that.

Comment: for the rest of us, "[Apiarist is a fancy word for a beekeeper.](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/apiarist)" Phys.org: [Nicotine enhances bees' activity](https://phys.org/news/2017-05-nicotine-bees.html) CBSNews: [Are bees getting addicted to nicotine?](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/are-bees-getting-addicted-to-nicotine-in-pesticides/) fyi the nicotine comes from neonicotinoid pesticides in places the bees visit, not from the bee-keepers' use of [smokers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_smoker).

Comment: Ok, well is there a consensus on how to do it without a smoker?

Comment: It'a a good question! If you would like to ask about beekeeping without a smoker, then it's better if you click "edit" and adjust the wording of your question along the lines of your comment. I don't think you want to ask about neonicotinoid pesticides, and the smokers can use various kinds of smoke. You might consider asking a second question also, as a new post, something like "How do beekeeper's smokers have a calming effect on Bees?"